# Указатель на std::function сразу в метод

Tags: c++, callback

Набросал вот [такой пример](https://ideone.com/qQt0WT):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

// ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

using CallbackType = std::function<void(void*)>;

// ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

class Karbofos {
  
    CallbackType *Begin = nullptr;
    CallbackType *End = nullptr;
  
  public:
  
    const std::string Name = "Карбофос";
    
    void SetCallback(CallbackType *B, CallbackType *E) {
      Begin = B;
      End = E;
    }
    
    void Run() {
      if (Begin) (*Begin)(this);
      std::cout << "- Не отдам, слон - мой!\n";
      if (End) (*End)(this);
    }
};

// ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

void Shef(void* i) {
  std::cout << "- Стой, живодер " << ((Karbofos*)(i))->Name << "!\n";   
}

// ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

void Kollega(void* i) {
  std::cout << "- " << ((Karbofos*)(i))->Name << ", ты немец и контрабандист!\n";   
}

// ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

int main() {
  Karbofos Object;  
  CallbackType S = Shef;
  CallbackType K = Kollega;
  Object.SetCallback(&S,&K);
  Object.Run();
  return 0;
}
```

**Вопрос**

Можно ли как-то обойтись без временных переменных `Chef` и `Kollega`, и сразу нужные ссылки передать в метод `SetCallback`?

Comment: Возможно `Object.SetCallback(new CallbackType(), new CallbackType());`

Comment: Точно! Переработался я)

Comment: Знакомо) сейчас вынесу в ответ.

Comment: Осталось как-то возможную утечку памяти подпилить хитрыми указателями.

Comment: А зачем вам указатели?

Comment: Если можно, давайте без них - вопрос, как от временных переменных `S` и `K` отказаться.

Comment: "А зачем вам указатели?" а, возможно я недопонял ... Так колбеки могут быть установлены, а могут быть и нет. Если установлены - нужно вызывать, если нет, соответственно, пропускать вызов.

Comment: @Majestio у `std::function` можно проверить установлена цель или нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам действительно необходимы указатели на `std::function`?
Тоже самое можно сделать и без них:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

//──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

using CallbackType = std::function<void(void*)>;

// ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

class Karbofos {
  
    CallbackType Begin;
    CallbackType End;
  
  public:
  
    const std::string Name = "Карбофос";

    void SetCallback(CallbackType B, CallbackType E) {
      Begin = std::move(B);
      End = std::move(E);
    }
    
    void Run() {
      if (Begin) Begin(this);
      std::cout << "- Не отдам, слон - мой!\n";
      if (End) End(this);
   }
};

// ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

void Shef(void* i) {
  std::cout << "- Стой, живодер " << ((Karbofos*)(i))->Name << "!\n";   
}

// ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 
void Kollega(void* i) {
  std::cout << "- " << ((Karbofos*)(i))->Name << ", ты немец и контрабандист!\n";   
}

// ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

int main() {
  Karbofos Object;  
  Object.SetCallback(Shef, Kollega);
  Object.Run();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Тока хедер `<utility>` для мува нужен

Comment: Да, так гораздо лучше!

Comment: И попутно вопрос, если не использовать std::move, то что?

Comment: @Majestio ничего, просто будет копирование, вместо перемещения.

Comment: @dIm0n добавил.

Answer (score 1):

Т.к. при создании объектов `Shef` и `Kollega` используется конструктор по умолчанию, получить аналогичные объекты (разве что с той лишь разницей, что память для них будет выделена в куче, а не в стеке) можно с помощью оператора `new` и пустых скобок после указания типа. То есть строки

```cpp
 CallbackType S = Shef;
 CallbackType K = Kollega;
 Object.SetCallback(&S,&K);
```

Заменятся на лаконичное

```cpp
Object.SetCallback(new CallbackType(), new CallbackType());
```

Также обращу внимание на то, что, т.к. память теперь выделена в куче, необходимо будет очистить её соответствующим `delete` после использования объектов, либо обернуть всё сие в умные указатели, например, так:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

// ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

using CallbackType = std::function<void(void*)>;

// ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

class Karbofos {

    // Тут поменял на соотв. типы
    std::shared_ptr<CallbackType> Begin = nullptr;
    std::shared_ptr<CallbackType> End = nullptr;

public:

    const std::string Name = "Карбофос";

    // Поменял типы аргументов
    void SetCallback(std::shared_ptr<CallbackType> B, std::shared_ptr<CallbackType> E) {
        Begin = B;
        End = E;
    }

    void Run() {
        if (Begin) (*Begin)(this);
        std::cout << "- Не отдам, слон - мой!\n";
        if (End) (*End)(this);
    }
};

// ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

void Shef(void* i) {
    std::cout << "- Стой, живодер " << ((Karbofos*)(i))->Name << "!\n";
}

// ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

void Kollega(void* i) {
    std::cout << "- " << ((Karbofos*)(i))->Name << ", ты немец и контрабандист!\n";
}

// ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

int main() 
{
    Karbofos Object;

    // Заменил здесь
    Object.SetCallback(std::shared_ptr<CallbackType>(new CallbackType(Shef)), std::shared_ptr<CallbackType>(new CallbackType(Kollega)));
    Object.Run();
    return 0;
}
```

P.S. Чтобы привести код к рабочему состоянию, мне потребовалось добавить `.c_str()` после `((Karbofos*)(i))->Name` при выводе в обоих случаях.

Comment: Запили, плс, еще вариант на хитрых указателях - и сразу жму зеленую галочку))

Comment: Сейчас попробую. Возможно получится кривенько, но работать должно.

Comment: Увы, пока вылетает с исключением, std::bad_function_call, см.тут - https://ideone.com/ZY9XDh

Comment: Ясн ... new CallbackType() - аргумента нет

Comment: Ну в общем - thx!)

Comment: @Majestio, хмм, а у меня и так взлетело. Тем не менее, рад помочь.

Comment: Вот последний вариант - https://ideone.com/dXS0oO

Comment: Там все заработало

Comment: Сорри, второй ответ более правильный!